# Prettier Config for react bracket spacing

Tags: reactjs, prettier

I want to know about if exists a prettier property for this

```js
// Code 
    <SomeReactComponent>
      {this.state.map((h) => <h1>h</h1>);}
    <SomeReactComponent/>

// Code expected 
    <SomeReactComponent>
     {
       this.state.map((h) => <h1>h</h1>);
     }
    <SomeReactComponent/>
```

My prettier config.

[prettier config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7yos.png)

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear. Can you provide more information regarding your requirement, please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exists a prettier property for this check this out:

```
"prettier.bracketSpacing": true
```

This should solve your question.

Comment: Works for classic javascript code but not in jsx templates

Comment: not working for ts at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you need that degree of control over formatting you're likely not the target audience for Prettier because such things are intentionally not configurable in it. See [Prettier's option philosophy](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html). That said, Prettier is open source, so you still can achieve what you want by forking it.